# Laravel Nova Action stop closing modal

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

is it possible to prevent closing a modal if control in the handle method is not valid in Nova Action?

Or, alternatively, is it possible to check value field with the value of another field?

Example.
2 fields year and event_date

```php
if($fields->year <> Carbon::parse($fields->event_date)->format('Y'))
  return Action::danger("Message");
```

This control close modal while rule control on single field prevent close modal

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try validate `fields()` on action before to execute in `handle()` method.

```
Date::make('Year')->rules('required', 'date'),
```

hope it will help you.